# How to create OracleDAO extends GenericDAO?

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee

I have in my application such GenericDAO

```
abstract public class GenericDAO<T extends BusinessObject> {
  public abstract T create(Class<T> o);
  public abstract T read(BigInteger id);
  public abstract void update(T o);
  public abstract void delete(T o);
}
```

How to create `OracleDAO<T extends BusinessObject> extends GenericDAO<T>`  ? I want to use `Generics`, but all business objects have different logic of creation `Statement`. Should I refuse `Generics`  and create specific `BusinessObjectOracleDAO` for every business object?

Comment: Generics isn't magic. It just increases type safety.

Answer (score 0):

The generic type `T` in this case refers to the object persisted by the DAO, not the database it came from.

I'd recommend that you let the package structure carry that information.

Put your generic DAO interface in a package named `persistence`, then have packages for each database implementation underneath it (e.g. `persistence.oracle`, `persistence.mysql`, etc.)  Each of these will have a GenericDaoImpl class that is tailored for the backing data store.

Personally I think this is a bad idea.  You shouldn't rely so much on a specific database.  It's possible to write that implementation in such a way that it'll work with any relational database with a JDBC driver. All you'll have to do to switch databases is implement the schema, port the data, and change the JAR for the driver.

Yes, you have to have DAOs for each class.  All the details are different: schema, query, mapping, creation.  You should isolate them as much as possible.

The best design I know of for this is Spring `JdbcTemplate` class.  It eliminates all the boilerplate and makes dealing with relational databases easy.